# How to check root environment variable from sudo user?

Tags: bash, sudo, environment-variables

How I may check root environment variables from sudo user? I tried various keys and combinations of su and sudo, but have no luck.

For example, $HISTFILESIZE=2000 for ordinary user and 9999 for root user.

```
vagrant@default-debian-78-64-nocm:~$ echo $HISTFILESIZE
2000
vagrant@default-debian-78-64-nocm:~$ sudo -i
root@default-debian-78-64-nocm:~# echo $HISTFILESIZE
9999
```

But when I try to get root $HISTFILESIZE via sudo - it always returns me a 2000:

```
vagrant@default-debian-78-64-nocm:~$ sudo -i echo $HISTFILESIZE
2000
vagrant@default-debian-78-64-nocm:~$ sudo -i su - -c "echo $HISTFILESIZE"
2000
vagrant@default-debian-78-64-nocm:~$ sudo -i bash -c "echo $HISTFILESIZE"
2000
vagrant@default-debian-78-64-nocm:~$ sudo -i bash -l -c "echo $HISTFILESIZE"
2000
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your shell will expand the variable before it even reaches `sudo`. Instead of

```
sudo -i echo $HISTFILESIZE
```

and all the variations, you need to escape it with a <kbd>\</kbd> as below:

```
sudo -i bash -c "echo \${HISTFILESIZE}"
```

*One more edit: need to bracket variable, it may contain spaces*

Comment: Not working, it returns '$HISTFILESIZE' string instead of it value

Comment: UPD:  `sudo -i bash -c "echo \$HISTFILESIZE" ` working correctly, thanks!